# Does it make sense for a callback to return a value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Commonly, an async function in js returns a promise wrapping either the resolved value or error message. If promise style do not apply, a callback can be passed as a parameter to that async function, in which the result of the async function is accessible.

Just wonder if it is meaningful for such a callback to have a r**eturn** statement? If so, who can receive the returned value and is there any useful use case?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/97u9pm6o/ It really doesn't make sense.... It's ugly code that makes my mind twist.

Comment: console.log("The result is",add(5,4, function(result) { return result;})), // The result is undefined

Comment: result is being returned to the add method. The add method is the one that should be console.logging. When return is added to a callback, it will return to where it was called.

Comment: No one receives the return value from a callback. The only effect of a `return`, whether with or without a value, is to return from the function.

Comment: @torazaburo,"the only effect"is not true,as denoted above,they calling function may need the return value of the callback.Although in this way,the callback is almost impossible to be async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of code to illustrate the concept you are trying to understand.

```
var callback = function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
    callAnotherFunction(result);
};

function getRandom(cb){
   //do something
   var result = Math.random();
   if(result > 0.5){
     return cb(result);
   }
   return cb(null, result);
}
getRandom(callback);
```

The function `getRandom()` will return an error if the random number is less than 0.5, a value otherwise. The callback then handles the response differently depending on the values passed to the callback function. As you can see, the `return` statement inside the callback makes a big difference. By the way, the above example demonstrates a standard [error-first design pattern](http://thenodeway.io/posts/understanding-error-first-callbacks/) in NodeJS.

Comment: Many thanks, excellent point ! Just seem to be more than 0.5 rather than less than

Comment: Ah! the curse of `<` vs `>`. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, any async function should return something like a handler, which you can use to track progress, or cancel the on-going async actions, example:

```
var timer = setTimeout(..)
clearTimeout(timer)
```

Because the return value is the only chance that you can get this handler in a sync manner, but it seems people don't quite care about this and invent all kinds of stuff to solve async cancellation problem, please read more about this on [my note](https://github.com/winterland1989/Action.js/wiki/Return-value-of-go) on [action-js](http://winterland1989.github.io/Action.js/).

In a perfect world, we should get a handler for every async function:

```
handler = fs.readFile('...', function(err, data){...});
xhr = ajax('...', function(err, data){...});
...
```